# import mysql data to hdfs using apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am learner of Apache nifi and currently expolering on "import mysql data to hdfs using apache nifi"

Please guide me on creating flow by providing an doc, end to end flow.
i have serached my sites, its not available.

Answer (score 1):

To import MySQL data, you would create a DBCPConnectionPool controller service, pointing at your MySQL instance, driver, etc.  Then you can use any of the following processors to get data from your database (please see the documentation for usage of each):

- [ExecuteSQL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL/index.html)
- [QueryDatabaseTable](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryDatabaseTable/index.html)
- [GenerateTableFetch](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GenerateTableFetch/index.html)

Once the data is fetched from the database, it is usually in Avro format. If you want it in another format, you will need to use some conversion processor(s) such as [ConvertAvroToJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.avro.ConvertAvroToJSON/index.html).  When the content of the flow file(s) is the way you want it, you can use [PutHDFS](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.PutHDFS/index.html) to place the files into HDFS.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for prompt reply .....I was stuck at creating DBCP connection Pool Controller service only......I am looking for any sample POC and End to end flow

Comment: I am facing below issue         in "QueryDatabaseTable"                                                  ListSFTP[id=744f7c9a-eb09-48b4-b65a-bb4974d7cc32] ListSFTP[id=744f7c9a-eb09-48b4-b65a-bb4974d7cc32] failed to invoke @OnScheduled method due to java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed while executing one of processor's OnScheduled task.; processor will not be scheduled to run for 30000 milliseconds: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed while executing one of processor's OnScheduled task.

Comment: 16:52:19 IST
ERROR
fac7e102-015a-1000-cc87-c57033b407cb

QueryDatabaseTable[id=fac7e102-015a-1000-cc87-c57033b407cb] QueryDatabaseTable[id=fac7e102-015a-1000-cc87-c57033b407cb] failed to invoke @OnScheduled method due to java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed while executing one of processor's OnScheduled task.; processor will not be scheduled to run for 30 seconds: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed while executing one of processor's OnScheduled task.

Comment: There should be more information in the log after that error, it might start with "Caused by:" can you share more of the log?

Comment: Check logs/nifi-app.log, looking for that same message. Then right below that message there should be more information as to why it failed